# SQL Server in Docker network: executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Tags: sql-server, docker

I want to create a Docker network and use it with a SQL Server.
Here is what I've done:

```
# Setup Network
sudo docker network create -d bridge dockerapi-dev

# Setup MSSQL Server
sudo docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server
sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=password" -p 1433:1433 -d mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server --network dockerapi-dev --name mssqlserver
```

Under `sudo docker network ls` my network "dockerapi-dev" shows up as "bridge" as I want it to.

With the last command, I get the following error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"--network\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is a hint that it thinks --network is part of the image to run.

Re-order your arguments like this (the image to run is last):

sudo docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=Y" -e "SA_PASSWORD=password" -p 1433:1433 -d --network dockerapi-dev --name mssqlserver mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server